# understanding a part of an awk program

Tags: awk

A friend of mine has written a code in unix

```
awk '\
BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; FS = "\t"} ;\
(NR >= 2){\
split($3,a,"|");\
if(a[1]!~ /\?/) {\
  print a[1], a[2] > "geneinfo_tumor.txt";\
  printf "%s", a[1] > "gene_tumor.txt";\
  for (i = 2; i <= 1099; i++)  printf "\t%g", log($i+1) > "gene_tumor.txt";\
  printf "\n" > "gene_tumor.txt";}\
}' tumor.exp.gt.txt
```

but I don't understand the following line

```
for (i = 2; i <= 1099; i++)  printf "\t%g", log($i+1) > "gene_tumor.txt";\
```

what does the log($i+1) do here ??

Answer (score 6):

In AWK, `log()` is the natural logarithm fonction, and `$i` is the value of the *i*th field in the current record. So `log($i+1)` takes the value of the *i*th field, adds 1, and returns the natural logarithm of the sum.

Comment: Thank you, so if I don't want to do log of the (field +1) and just add the value of the field what should I replace the log($i+1) with ?

Comment: Just `$i` then.

Comment: could you please explain the whole code for me if you don't mind